# Why do we use UNION to join rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, operators, union, rows, alter

Why use union in Sql at all when there must be same order of columns and it's names in the select statements. Couldn't we just update or alter the table to add more rows ?

Comment: why do we print new books if we can just add sheets of paper into existing one?

Comment: "Why use a screwdriver when you can just use a hammer?  What's the point of a screwdriver?"  Because not everything is a nail.

Comment: Couldn't we just update or alter the table to add more rows ; -  and if the business says no? or db design has separated tables or some tables don;t have the same layout etc. You should really do a bit more research..

Comment: I'm not sure about that one.  But could you explain me this. Like isn't it harder to create new tables and join them using union than to add new rows to existing tables ?

Comment: @Juggle: By that logic, all data should always ever be stored in one table.  Perhaps you have a *specific example* of what you're asking?  It's entirely possible that `UNION` isn't the ideal tool for whatever you happen to be doing right now.  But whatever task you're working on right now isn't *the entirety of all tasks anybody will ever perform in a database*.

Comment: @juggle you can do whatever you like within the constraints imposed by the db schema the queries you wish to run against it and business rules

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should. I just asked the question soon as I learnt about unions.  @P.Salmon

Comment: @David I have just started learning about unions and one of the examples in the material was adding two tables with 3 columns: student name, ID, marks. Adding the rows with union just felt unnecessary here. But I understand that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you would not just keep adding rows to a single table is that they don't belong in that table.

For the same reason that if you're doing arithmetic between two integer variables like `x + y`, you don't permanently add the value of `y` to `x`. You want to preserve `x`'s value as it's own thing, even though sometimes you also need the sum.

A book like [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491941170) makes clear that there's a difference between a *relation* and a *relvar*. A relvar is like a table. It's a persistent storage of a specific set of rows.

A relation is the result of a SQL expression like SELECT or VALUES. That relation may not be stored in any relvar; it is ephemeral. Perhaps it's the result of a more complex query that uses expressions, joins, and so on.

By analogy, the a number like 42 is an *integer value*. But `int x` that stores an integer value 42 is an *integer variable*. They can both be used as an operand for `+` but they're not the same kind of thing.

You can UNION two relations, if their columns are compatible in number and data type. Those relations aren't necessarily just relvars, they could be the result of other subqueries.

Just like in arithmetic, you can add `x` and a whole other integer expression.